# Windows, Linux won't boot from any disk, were working before

Tags: boot, bsod, computer-building, memtest86+, kernel-panic

I'm having a really strange problem. About a month ago I built a new computer. I installed Windows on it and later I bought another SSD and installed Fedora there. Everything has been working perfectly until yesterday. While I was using Windows I got a BSOD. Rebooted and got it during boot. Every time.

I tried to reinstall Windows from an USB stick. At first I couldn't get it to boot, I would get another BSOD. Eventually, after multiple tries, the installer booted and I could reinstall Windows.

But then, the new install wouldn't boot. Tried booting Fedora and it didn't work. A Fedora live usb booted perfectly. Installed Fedora again and it works but the graphic server crashes randomly.

I tried using another memory module: the problem persisted. I tried using the integrated graphics: the problem persisted. The processor passes Intel Processor Diagnostic Tool tests perfectly.

It's really strange and I don't know what to do next. Does anybody have any clue on what could be causing this problem?

System:

- CPU: Intel - Core i5-7500 3.4GHz Quad-Core Processor
- CPU Cooler: be quiet! - PURE ROCK 51.7 CFM Sleeve Bearing CPU Cooler -
- Motherboard: Gigabyte - GA-B250M-DS3H Micro ATX LGA1151 Motherboard
- Memory: Crucial - Ballistix Sport LT 8GB (1 x 8GB) DDR4-2400 Memory
- Storage: Samsung - 850 EVO-Series 500GB 2.5" Solid State Drive, SanDisk G26 Plus 120GB 2.5" Solid State Drive
- Video Card: EVGA - GeForce GTX 1060 6GB 6GB SC GAMING Video Card
- Case: be quiet! - Pure Base 600 (Black) ATX Mid Tower Case
- Power Supply: be quiet! - Pure Power 10 500W 80+ Silver Certified ATX Power Supply
- Wireless Network Adapter: Gigabyte - GC-WB867D-I PCI-Express x1 802.11a/b/g/n/ac Wi-Fi Adapter

Software:
Windows 10, Fedora 26

Comment: Download the Samsung SSD diagnostic toll and post the results here please. I suspect the SSD is failing

Comment: @TomEus Hm, I tried on the other SSD I have and it doesn't work. But I can try that tool.

Comment: The problem is probably hardware, but I have no idea how to find it from here. A workshop would just swap components to find the bad one. Did you change anything before it happened, connected new hardware etc.?

Comment: @harrymc nope, I didn't change anything. I also think that it's a hardware problem but I don't know how to find it. I can't start swapping parts just because I don't have them :(

Comment: Well, we know it's not the disk. Reducing RAM to the minimum and swapping sticks will test it. Be creative for the rest.

Comment: Try switching between IDE and AHCI modes on your disk controller, using BIOS and try installing again.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably hardware, but we cannot answer it here - there are
just too many possibilities.
This is a job for a workshop that has enough exchange parts to detect
the problem.

I suggest to reset everything, including the BIOS, to initial values;
undo overclocking (if any);
and to disconnect every possible device, then swapping the essential ones
that are left.
If you still have no idea where the problem is,
consulting a professional might help.

Comment: Why do you have only one RAM stick? This means you don't have dual channel. Better 2 x 4GB than 1 x 8GB.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your Boot-priority is set wrong. I suggest entering the EFI/BIOS and change Boot-priority to whatever you like, but not this.